# Progressbar update causing a black screen

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am trying to update the progressbar, but it is showing a black screen whenever I use progressbar. As soon as I comment the part of progressbar increment, my code works fine. Could someone please help me out with what am I doing wrong?

```
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < timeout; i++) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressbar.incrementProgressBy(1);
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }.run();
```

Comment: haven't you forget to create a `Thread` here ?

Comment: I have not used threading much, but from what I read from net. I am using a anonymous interface for thread, and interface way is Runnable. So, why would I need to create a Thread class here too ? I saw that at some codes, but didn't understood. Would be great if you could explain please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this code on your main thread .

```
 new CountDownTimer(3000, 300) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

            progress = progress + 10;
            pb.setProgress(progress);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            pb.setProgress(100);


        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Although I appreciate your support, I would like if you could explain me a bit about what I did wrong in my code. I want to learn what I did wrong rather than just fixing code . . . .

Comment: @IshChhabra you should avoid using UI changes in threads . Because threads are not related to activity's or fragment's life-cycle it will call your code before or after your view is set .

Comment: Okay, thanks. However, if there was a necessity to use threads in some case, what would be the correct way for it?

Comment: @IshChhabra Yhh sure you can but must take care of such case like memory leakage . Can you accept my answer here ?

Answer (score 2):

using thread you can do like this...

```
public void loadProgressbar()
{
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (progress = 0; progress <= 100; progress++) {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    }
                });


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why we can't use an anonymous Runnable interface and need to use an outer anonymous Thread class, too ? I have seen various examples with anonymous Runnable only